# Aging cheese contaminates levain

Tags: cheese, yeast

I took my levain from the fridge, fed it and put it in the counter, besides a cheese which is aging. The levain pot had no lid and the cheese has a cloth mesh over it. One day later the levain did not start, and was smelling like cheese. Would it be a good idea to recover the levain to benefit from this? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm afraid the only real answer to this question is "go and experiment".